# C++Builder communication among Frames

Tags: frame, c++builder

Good day.
There is a main form

```
frmMain:
    Button1
    Panel1
```

and frames

```
Frame1:
    Label1
    Button1
    Panel1

Frame2:
   StringGrid1 - attached to the database table 

Frame1::Button1OnClick()
{
    Frame2 = new TFrmame2(Application);
    Frame2->Parent = Panel1;
}


TFrame2::StringGrid1SelectCell(TObject *Sender, const int ACol, const int ARow,
          bool &CanSelect)
{
    Frame1->Label1->Text = StringGrid1->Cells[ACol][ARow];
}
```

I get an error - access violation
Help solve the problem

Comment: Where is `Frame1` actually defined, and where is it assigned to point at a valid `TFrame1` object? Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score -1):

```
void __fastcall TForm1::btn1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
Frame1= new TFrame1(Application);
Frame1->Parent = Panel1;
}
```

```
void __fastcall TFrame1::Button1Click(TObject* Sender)
{
    TFrame* Frame2 = new TFrame2(Application);
    Frame2->Parent = Panel1;
}
```

```
void __fastcall TFrame2::StringGrid1SelectCell(TObject *Sender, const int ACol, const int ARow,
          bool &CanSelect)
{
    Frame1->Label1->Text = StringGrid1->Cells[ACol][ARow];
}
```

Interesting.
I did not change anything in the code.
I just rearranged the frame names.
Everything works.

Comment: Answers cannot be questions.